# RMI dynamic class loading

Tags: java, rmi

I'm trying to learn RMI. Managed to launch a simple example but I can't achieve dynamic loading of classes.

**Hello.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.rmi.Remote; 
import java.rmi.RemoteException;  

public interface Hello extends Remote {
   String greet(String name) throws RemoteException;
}
```

**HelloImpl.java**

```
package com.example;

public class HelloImpl implements Hello {  
   public String greet(String name) {
      System.out.println("Call from " + name);
      return "Hello " + name + "!";
   }  
}
```

**Server.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server extends HelloImpl {
   public Server() {}

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
      try {
         HelloImpl greeter = new HelloImpl();

         Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(greeter, 0);
         Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
         registry.bind("Hello", stub);

         System.err.println("Server ready");
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.rmi.Naming; 

public class Client {
   private Client() {}

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
      try {
         Hello stub = (Hello) Naming.lookup("//localhost/Hello");

         System.out.println(stub.greet(args[0]));
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.err.println("Client exception: " + e.toString());
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

**rmi.policy**

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I started rmiregistry, web-server and executed `java -Djava.security.policy=rmi.policy com.example.Server`. When I try to start the client application with command

```
java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=http://localhost:8000/ -Djava.security.policy=rmi.policy com.example.Client Hivemaster
```

web-server get request

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2017 14:06:45] "GET /com/example/Hello.class HTTP/1.1" 200
```

but program get exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/Hello
        at com.example.Client.main(Client.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.Hello
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the client is using the `Hello` interface by name, it must be present on its classpath. Same as it does when compiling it.

The codebase feature is for classes *derived from* those mentioned in remote interfaces. In this case there is no apparent need to use the codebase feature at all: but if you do, the codebase property needs to be set at the JVM which is sending instances of those classes.